# Why does a symmetry operator commute with the Hamiltonian?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, symmetry, hamiltonian, commutator

Suppose that a [symmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_in_quantum_mechanics) operator $O$ leaves the Hamiltonian $H$ unchanged. From books I know that there should be the relation $OH=HO$. But I don't understand why it is not that $H=HO$ since when the operator acts on a wave function we have $H\psi=H(O\psi)$ (The effect of the Hamiltonian before and after $O$ acts on the wave function is the same). Can someone explain it?

Comment: Please explain your last statement: Why should $H\psi = H (O\psi)$?

Comment: The effect of the Hamiltonian before and after $O$ acts on the wave function is the same.

Comment: Your intuition behind proposing $H\psi=H(O\psi)$ is that if $O$ is a symmetry then it should leave the wavefunction invariant?

Comment: Possibly. I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The confusion may be because in classical physics, the Hamiltonian is a *scalar* function of the state, and a symmetry transformation on the state does indeed leave the Hamiltonian *invariant*. However, the quantum operator $H$ is not a scalar function but maps a state vector to another vector (in the Hilbert space). $H$ determines the evolution of the wave function via the time-dependent Schrödinger equation
$$i\hbar\frac{d\psi}{dt} = H\psi.$$
Given that $\psi$ is a solution of this equation, we should still have a solution if we replace it by the transformed wave function $O\psi$ at all times. Thus,
$$i\hbar\frac{d(O\psi)}{dt} = HO\psi.$$
Using the original equation, the left-hand side here reduces to $OH\psi$. Thus the symmetry preserves solutions if $OH = HO$.

Answer (score 5):

If $O$ is a symmetry and $\psi$ is an energy eigen-state, then $O\psi$ should also be an energy eigenstate (with the same eigenvalue $E$).

With the equation that you propose, $HO = H$, we have :
$$HO\psi = H\psi = E\psi\neq EO\psi$$

On the other hand, with $HO = OH$, we have :
$$HO \psi = OH\psi =EO\psi$$
so $O\psi$ has indeed energy $E$.

Answer (score 4):

This confusion is probably caused by sloppy language: The $O$ in $[H,O] = HO - OH = 0$ for a "symmetry" $O$ is not actually the symmetry, it is the *symmetry generator* (or "infinitesimal symmetry") - the one-parameter unitary operator $U_O(\epsilon) = \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}O\epsilon}$ associated to $O$ via [Stone's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%27s_theorem_on_one-parameter_unitary_groups) is the actual *symmetry operator* (in the sense of [Wigner's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%27s_theorem) which says all symmetries are (anti-)unitary and $O$ is Hermitian, not unitary) for which the Hamiltonian is "unchanged" as in
$$ U_O(\epsilon)HU_O(\epsilon)^\dagger= H.$$
This is now really the statement that the symmetry leaves the Hamiltonian invariant and should be our actual definition of what it means for an operator to be a symmetry. This equation, in turn, implies for the generator that $[H,O] = 0$ (e. g. via application of the [BCH formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#An_important_lemma_and_its_application_to_a_special_case_of_the_Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula)).

Comment: Why do you say that the $O$ in the question should refer to the generator and not to the symmetry? The symmetry operator itself ($U$ in your notation) also satisfies $[H,U] = HU - UH = 0$.

Comment: @Noiralef You're right, but I view that as an "accident", not how you *should* think about it: On a more abstract level (i.e. thinking about symmetry algebras and groups and not as their concrete realizations on a Hilbert space), the commutator/Lie bracket is an operation on the level of the algebra, and the action of $U$ on $H$ is the adjoint action of a group element on the algebra ($H$ is in the algebra because it is itself a generator of time translation). This adjoint action becomes a commutator only when expressing everything as concrete matrices/operators.

Comment: I see your point, if $O$ in the question was supposed to be the symmetry operator, the relation would more usually be expressed in the form $OHO^{-1} = H$. Well, now OP has several answers to choose from, depending on what they actually meant by $O$ :-)

Answer (score 2):

It might be instructive to look at a concrete example. Let's consider $L^2(\mathbb R^2)$, that is, wave functions $\psi(x,y)$ in 2D space and the Hamiltonian $H = \partial_x^2 + \partial_y^2$. We would expect this to be symmetric under rotations of the coordinate system, such as the 90° rotation
$$ (O\psi)(x,y) = \psi(y, -x) . $$

Let us evaluate:

- $(H\psi)(x,y) = \psi_{11}(x,y) + \psi_{22}(x,y) $ (where I use subscripts to denote the partial derivative with respect to the first / second argument)
- $(HO\psi)(x,y) = \psi_{22}(y, -x) + \psi_{11}(y, -x)$

These are not the same and the reason is that the two functions $H\psi$ and $HO\psi$ "live" in different coordinate systems. So what we really want to compare $HO\psi$ to is

- $(OH\psi)(x,y) = \psi_{11}(y, -x) + \psi_{22}(y, -x)$

A useful next exercise might be to try and see where it goes wrong for the Hamiltonian $H_2 = \partial_x^2$, which is not rotationally symmetric.